# Android Studio not recognizing gradle 2.10

Tags: google-app-engine, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

This question is kind of two fold, I am trying to update my google app engine backend and i keep getting this error:

```
:contentbackend:appengineUpdate
Please enter code: Encountered a problem: No line found
```

I was reading around and saw people saying this issue is related to Android Studio and to just manually trigger appengineUpdate like this:

```
gradlew contentbackend:apengineUpdate
```

So everytime i try that im getting this error now:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 1.12. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Users\nicholas\AndroidStudioProjects\TTWebContent\contentbackend\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

Now i have gone through my project and module setting and made sure everything points to gradle wrapper version 2.10, but i still get this error when trying to updateAppngine. I am using the appengine plugin version 1.9.34. I am aware that this has all moved to using OAuth2.0 so that what im trying to get configured so i can update the backend using the new sdk. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Here is the content of my gradlewrapper.properties

```
#Mon Dec 28 10:00:20 PST 2015
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trouble i got this working. So i was trying to execute this command from windows powershell, not understanding the instructions from similiar posts saying to do this manually instead of using Android Studio. I got this to work by using the built in 'terminal' in Android Studio. I always thought when people specified to execute manually they meant outside of Android Studio, I now understand they meant using the terminal built in. This is no longer an issue and it let me enter the OAuth key so i could update my backend.